# Separate questions by Error / Bug / Misbehaviour / Etc

Tags: feature-request

I was wondering if it would be interesting to rather than have something like just tags for **Error** or **Bug** or **Misbehaviour** or others, have a sort of separate types of questions where the user can define the question as something like needing help with an *error* they don't understand, a behaviour being different from expected or others so that when answering questions we can classify them by type of question so that a possible responder may know what type of answer the questioner is looking for.

For example a question relating to code that a user does not understand would require an answer that dwells into more abstract concepts of the language for example. Whereas an **Error** type of question is rather looking for an explicit solution to an error rather than an abstract explanation for the concept in question.

It might help people answering to know what the answer is going to look like rather than using just intuition which sometimes leads to questions looking for an explanation to an error rather than a solution getting just solutions if they forgot to state it in the question.

It might also help users answering if they are for example recent and not as knowledgeable as other users to answer questions that are more in their scope of knowledge. A student like me for example will find it easier to solve an error (since as students we run into them constantly and are very aware of them) than a question looking for the explanation of why maybe python doesn't declare variables which are easily badly answered since we have less knowledge than a professional worker for example.

So in summary a possibility of sorting questions not only by tag but also by **TYPE** which currently is not really possible.

I haven't seen anything similar asked here so I hope this isn't a duplicate.

Don't hesitate to answer harshly if this is not a good thing, I just thought about it whilst scrolling through questions and having to click on all to see if they were anywhere near my scope of knowledge.

I hope this can contribute to helping new users rather than older more experienced ones.

Thank you for your time, and sorry for the long post ( TL;DR on the comments I guess haha)

Comment: 1. A user who is stuck probably doesn't know what type they have (for example, many people interpret their trivial errors as language bugs). 2. If the question is unclear or open to interpretation it needs editing, not tagging. 3. If a user can't determine whether a question is in their scope of knowledge by *actually reading it*, the problem is in the question or the user, not the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is a good idea, at all.

The tags you describe are at best meta tags, similar like homework. Those type of tags are irrelevant for any visitor of that question. Anyone interested in certain questions will never search for [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) (unless you are on Meta and an SE dev). If you describe on the tag [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) you'll get questions in your feed from all kind of tool- and language stacks. How would the users that can answer possible questions wade through that lot?

Those tags would also have a huge amount of questions in them, making it hard, if not impossible, to find anything useful. Instead of being beneficial for future visitors, their search experience will be ruined.

Choosing tags is already difficult. If an OP now also has to choose a correct meta tag I foresee a lot of of mis-tagging and a lot of *this is not a bug, this is misbehavior* comments.

Don't forget that Stack Overflow is only a little bit on answering a question for the OP. The Q and A is even more meant for future visitors who have a similar issue. That is what sets us apart from regular forums, where the focus is on the OP.